First time error in journal
Today I saw this error for the fist time in the journal:
percpu: allocation failed, size=8 align=8 atomic=1, atomic alloc failed, no space left

What does it mean?
The system is Xubuntu 22.04.5 running the 6.8.0-49-generic kernel.
Thank you.
